# Run 10 bots with 1 script without rewrite 10 times the code (discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, discord, discord.py

I created 10 discord bots for fun in my discord server, I want to create the same function for every bot, but for write a simple bot command I need to write 40 lines of code, is there any way to get the code shorter? Because is very booring to write the same code 10 times. This is my code.

```
import asyncio
import random
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot_1 = commands.Bot(command_prefix='()')
bot_2 = commands.Bot(command_prefix='()')
bot_3 = commands.Bot(command_prefix='()')
bot_4 = commands.Bot(command_prefix='()')
bot_5 = commands.Bot(command_prefix='()')
bot_6 = commands.Bot(command_prefix='()')
bot_7 = commands.Bot(command_prefix='()')
bot_8 = commands.Bot(command_prefix='()')
bot_9 = commands.Bot(command_prefix='()')
bot_10 = commands.Bot(command_prefix='()')


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

loop.create_task(bot_1.start("token 1"))
loop.create_task(bot_2.start("token 2"))
loop.create_task(bot_3.start("token 3"))
loop.create_task(bot_4.start("token 4"))
loop.create_task(bot_5.start("token 5"))
loop.create_task(bot_6.start("token 6"))
loop.create_task(bot_7.start("token 7"))
loop.create_task(bot_8.start("token 8"))
loop.create_task(bot_9.start("token 9"))
loop.create_task(bot_10.start("token 10"))

@bot_1.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Tutti i bot sono stati caricati correttamente.\n")


@bot_1.command()
async def parola_casuale(ctx):
    file = open("Parole.txt", "r")
    parole = file.readlines()
    parola = random.choice(parole)
    await ctx.message.channel.send(f"Ecco a te: {parola}")
@bot_2.command()
async def parola_casuale(ctx):
    file = open("Parole.txt", "r")
    parole = file.readlines()
    parola = random.choice(parole)
    await ctx.message.channel.send(f"Ecco a te: {parola}")
@bot_3.command()
async def parola_casuale(ctx):
    file = open("Parole.txt", "r")
    parole = file.readlines()
    parola = random.choice(parole)
    await ctx.message.channel.send(f"Ecco a te: {parola}")
@bot_4.command()
async def parola_casuale(ctx):
    file = open("Parole.txt", "r")
    parole = file.readlines()
    parola = random.choice(parole)
    await ctx.message.channel.send(f"Ecco a te: {parola}")
@bot_5.command()
async def parola_casuale(ctx):
    file = open("Parole.txt", "r")
    parole = file.readlines()
    parola = random.choice(parole)
    await ctx.message.channel.send(f"Ecco a te: {parola}")
@bot_6.command()
async def parola_casuale(ctx):
    file = open("Parole.txt", "r")
    parole = file.readlines()
    parola = random.choice(parole)
    await ctx.message.channel.send(f"Ecco a te: {parola}")
@bot_7.command()
async def parola_casuale(ctx):
    file = open("Parole.txt", "r")
    parole = file.readlines()
    parola = random.choice(parole)
    await ctx.message.channel.send(f"Ecco a te: {parola}")
@bot_8.command()
async def parola_casuale(ctx):
    file = open("Parole.txt", "r")
    parole = file.readlines()
    parola = random.choice(parole)
    await ctx.message.channel.send(f"Ecco a te: {parola}")
@bot_9.command()
async def parola_casuale(ctx):
    file = open("Parole.txt", "r")
    parole = file.readlines()
    parola = random.choice(parole)
    await ctx.message.channel.send(f"Ecco a te: {parola}")
@bot_10.command()
async def parola_casuale(ctx):
    file = open("Parole.txt", "r")
    parole = file.readlines()
    parola = random.choice(parole)
    await ctx.message.channel.send(f"Ecco a te: {parola}")


try:
    loop.run_forever()
finally:
    loop.stop()
```

(I can't post this because is mostly code)(I can't post this because is mostly code)(I can't post this because is mostly code)(I can't post this because is mostly code)(I can't post this because is mostly code)(I can't post this because is mostly code)(I can't post this because is mostly code)(I can't post this because is mostly code)(I can't post this because is mostly code)(I can't post this because is mostly code)(I can't post this because is mostly code)(I can't post this because is mostly code)

Comment: Why do you need 10 bots that do the same exact thing? By the way just use a loop.

Comment: for fun, like move player, spam messages or play music.

Comment: But you can't add the same bot multiple times to the same server as far as I know.

Comment: I use 10 different bots (with 10 different token) it works

Comment: Then create one bot, and call them in a loop with the different codes. Use a for loop, and lists.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand, can you show me an example? I'm beginner in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could look something like

```
import asyncio
import random
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKENS = ["token 1"
          "token 2"
          "token 3"
          "token 4"
          "token 5"
          "token 6"
          "token 7"
          "token 8"
          "token 9"
          "token 10"]

async def on_ready():
    print("Tutti i bot sono stati caricati correttamente.\n")

async def parola_casuale(ctx):
    file = open("Parole.txt", "r")
    parole = file.readlines()
    parola = random.choice(parole)
    await ctx.message.channel.send(f"Ecco a te: {parola}")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

for token in TOKENS:
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='()')
    loop.create_task(bot.start(token))
    bot.event(on_ready)
    bot.command()(parola_casuale)

try:
    loop.run_forever()
finally:
    loop.stop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help now the code works succesfully.

Answer (score -1):

Use a loop, and a list:

```
import asyncio
import random
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bots = [] #empty
tokens = ["key1","key2"] #here should be all the keys

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Tutti i bot sono stati caricati correttamente.\n")


@bot.command()
async def parola_casuale(ctx):
    file = open("Parole.txt", "r")
    parole = file.readlines()
    parola = random.choice(parole)
    await ctx.message.channel.send(f"Ecco a te: {parola}")

for i in range(len(tokens)): #for every token
    bots.append(commands.Bot(command_prefix='()')) #create a bot
    loop.create_task(bot[i].start(tokens[i])) #start the bot
```

Comment: loop.create_task(bot[i].start(tokens[i])) return a syntax error. Why?

Comment: Can you please post the error code? I can't really replicate your code due to the lack of tokens.

Comment: It return this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "(my directory)", line 22, in <module>
    @bot.event
NameError: name 'bot' is not defined