# Running multiple bots in 1 script without warning

Tags: python, discord.py

**Goals**

Running multiple bot in the same time with same command

**What I've tried**

I've coded and searching through internet I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63734897/discord-py-run-2-instances-of-a-bot-in-one-script). I know it's the answer but if I created `client1` and `client2`. Here in my code I just make 1 client (`client1`)

```
token1 = getenv("TOKEN1")
token2 = getenv("TOKEN2")

intents = discord.Intents().all()
client1 = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.', intents = intents)
slash = SlashCommand(client1, sync_commands=True)
client1.remove_command('help')

@client1.event
async def on_ready():
    await client1.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name='Bot Ready'))
    print("logged in")

for filename in listdir('cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client1.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')

def meFunction(ctx):
    return ctx.author.id == 385053392059236353

loop =  asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(client1.start(token1))
loop.create_task(client1.start(token2))
loop.run_forever()
```

And then this warning message appear in my command prompt

```
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x00000247DB381BE0>
Unclosed connector
connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x00000247DB370D60>, 2262.609)]']
connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x00000247DB38E280>
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-5' coro=<Client.start() done, defined at C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py:649> exception=RuntimeError('Concurrent call to receive() is not allowed')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 666, in start
    await self.connect(reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 566, in connect
    await self.ws.poll_event()
  File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 555, in poll_event
    msg = await self.socket.receive(timeout=self._max_heartbeat_timeout)
  File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client_ws.py", line 216, in receive
    raise RuntimeError("Concurrent call to receive() is not allowed")
RuntimeError: Concurrent call to receive() is not allowed
```

**Last solution what I know** is making `client2` which is copy of `client1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run 10 bots with 1 script without rewrite 10 times the code (discord.py)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64795342/run-10-bots-with-1-script-without-rewrite-10-times-the-code-discord-py)

Comment: And then what if i want to add cog to it? @TheFungusAmongUs

Comment: The same way you're doing it in this code, just in the loop.